# Члены предложения.

Tags: синтаксис

Чем в предложении "Хлынули оглушительные потоки звуков и затопили лес" является слово "звуков"?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы определиться с синтаксической ролью слова, нужно прежде всего найти то слово, от которого оно зависит. В данном предложении таковым является лексема потоки. Следующий шаг -- поставить вопрос к проблемному компоненту словосочетания. В нашем случае возможны два варианта: потоки (чего?) звуков и потоки (какие?) звуков. Первый вопрос морфологический (вопрос косвенных падежей), а второй -- синтаксический. При определении синтаксической роли слова в предложении "побеждает" синтаксический вопрос. Поэтому данное слово действительно является несогласованным определением. Кроме того, может помочь приём синонимической замены. Так, словосочетание с несогласованным определением потоки звуков легко заменяется на звуковые потоки. А ещё следует учитывать и значение членов предложения как таковых. Дополнение, как правило, обозначает объект, а определение -- признак. А в данном примере слово звуков уж точно не является объектом, на который направлено действие или с помощью которого оно совершается.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "звуков" отвечает на вопрос "кого-чего" и является дополнением.

Answer (score 1):

А может быть и несогласованным определением: потоки какие? Звучные.

Answer (score 1):

Это несогласованное определение! Такие определения, конечно, будут иметь либо оттенок дополнения,либо обстоятельства. Но это определение.